# Normal subgroups

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

To typeset that H is a normal subgroup of G, I would use `H\unlhd G`.

However, the result doesn't satisfy myself, since the G seems too close to the 
triangle:

[image]

Adding a space `\` makes "too much space".

Is there a neat way to typeset such a thing ?

Comment: There is also an half-space ``\,``.

Comment: Since this is used as a relation, use `\mathrel{\unlhd}` instead. It will allow for the appropriate spacing around the operator/relation. How do you currently typeset the relation - please show the entire code that produced the image. It seems like you might not be using math mode correctly.

Comment: @Werner, I simply typed `$H\unlhd G` inside a paragraph. Your solution works really fine, thank you!

Comment: For very bizarre reasons **latexsym** classifies `\unlhd` as a binary operation symbol. Either use the command suggested by Martin, or say in your preamble `\DeclareMathSymbol\unlhd{\mathrel}{lasy}{"02}`, after `\usepackage{latexsym}`; in this way `$H\unlhd G$` will render correctly.

Comment: By the way, in all of these answers, it's probably a good idea for you to define a personal macro for this symbol, like `\nsub` (normal subgroup?).  That way, first, you save a lot of writing, and second, if you decide again that you hate the symbol, you can change it easily.  Semantic markup and all that.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The same symbol is also available as `\trianglelefteq` from the `amssymb` package. It gives a much wider spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$H\trianglelefteq G$
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 23):

Appropriate math spacing for relational operators is obtained using `\mathrel`:

```
$H\mathrel{\unlhd}G$
```