# LaTeX inconsistent spacing? Is this normal?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

```
\subsection{Third Isomorphism Theorem}
Let $G$ be a group, and $N\unlhd G$, $K\unlhd G$ such that $N\subseteq K\subseteq G$. Then $(G/N)/(K/N)\cong G/K$.
\subsection{Correspondence Theorem}
Let $N\unlhd G$. There exists a bijection $\phi:\{\text{all subgroups $H$ such that $N\subseteq H\subseteq G$}\}\to\{\text{subgroups of $G/N$}\}$, with $\phi(H)=H/N$.
%%%
```

I refer to the above code which returns the output below. The issue I am refering to is the width of `N\unlhd G`, which clearly appears "wider" in the first instance, and narrower in the second instance. Is this normal?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Well, it's justification

Comment: Is this something that should be left alone as it is, or is it customary to fix it?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37205/normal-subgroups

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For very mysterious reasons, `latexsym` defines `\unlhd` as a `\mathbin` instead of a `\mathrel`.

On the other hand, `amssymb` provides a better symbol, `\trianglelefteq`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand{\unlhd}{\trianglelefteq}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Third Isomorphism Theorem}
Let $G$ be a group, and $N\unlhd G$, $K\unlhd G$ such that $N\subseteq K\subseteq G$. Then $(G/N)/(K/N)\cong G/K$.
\subsection{Correspondence Theorem}
Let $N\unlhd G$. There exists a bijection $\phi:\{\text{all subgroups $H$ such that $N\subseteq H\subseteq G$}\}\to\{\text{subgroups of $G/N$}\}$, with $\phi(H)=H/N$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

the difference here is caused by the different treatment of two different
classes of symbols when the lines in which they occur are justified.

the two classes involved here are `\mathbin` (for `\unlhd`, a binary operator)
and `\mathrel` (for `\subseteq`, a relation).

in the second example, the line is too long to fit, so spacing is compressed
where permitted.  compression is not applied as severely around relations,
but it *is* applied around binary operators.  in the first example, there
is no place to break in the math string at the end of the sentence, so all
the spaces in the first line are exaggerated, making the difference more
obvious.

it's not really a good idea to try to "correct" this manually.  a better
approach is to reword the two examples so that they don't encounter the
problem.  (another approach is to use ragged right, so that all spaces
are set at their "natural" width.)